# How important is it to find a deterministic polynomial time algorithm to construct Ramanujan graphs?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reference-request

As in I don't know what is the difference between say the conferences SODA, STOC or FOCS. Measured in terms of such conferences, where would such a result be publishable?

This is not a "technical" question.
I want to understand how importantly does the community view this question if hypothetically someone does this.

---

May be you can just comment and not write an "answer"

Comment: Is there no such algorithm known?

Comment: As far as I know, no

Comment: You could publish it in any of the three conferences, though STOC and FOCS are considered more prestigious than SODA.

Comment: think this is not opinion based as (currently) two close votes because "important" can be taken as a shorthand for "applications"

Answer (score 3):

There is already an explicit construction of Ramanujan graphs, due to Margulis and (separately) Lubotzky–Philips–Sarnak. Their construction only gives graphs with degree $p+1$ for some prime $p$. Later this was extended to cover prime powers $p$.

Recently, [Marcus, Spielman and Srivastava](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4132) gave a probabilistic construction of bipartite Ramanujan graphs of all degrees, and the paper appeared in FOCS 2013, and is due to appear in the Annals of Mathematics. This construction cannot even be implemented by an efficient probabilistic algorithm, and only works for bipartite graphs. In very recent work, the same authors extend their method to give bipartite Ramanujan graphs of all degrees and all sizes, in work that was submitted to FOCS 2015 (per Adam Marcus's homepage).

The community finds the recent line of work exciting not only because of the results themselves, but also because of the very interesting technique, which while (as far as I understand) not entirely new, has reached a new level of sophistication and applications. Improving on their results, either to get efficient algorithms or to remove the bipartiteness assumption, will likely require new techniques, and so will be exciting for the community.

While both papers mentioned above were submitted to FOCS, this is just due to coincidence; they might as well have been submitted to STOC. There is no real difference between these conferences, other than the time of year in which they take place, and the organization sponsoring them. SODA is considered less prestigious than FOCS and STOC.

Comment: uh, "no real difference" between two completely different conferences? accept the idea in general but think it needs some rough qualification... also this doesnt really say anything about applications...

Comment: @vzn That's right, no real difference beyond the organization backing it. As for applications, I believe that Ramanujan graphs have no applications. I asked a few people who work in the area about that, and they always replied that it was a "natural" notion, but it has no applications; applications usually don't care so much how good your expander is, and even when they do, an almost Ramanujan graph – which a random graph is asymptotically almost surely – is as good as a Ramanujan graph.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am saying - say someone manages to take these MSS ideas and packages them in a way that makes it into a deterministic polynomial time algorithm. Will that be important enough for STOC or FOCS?

Comment: if the conferences have nearly identical aims/ structure/ dynamics etc then one wonders why they dont just merge. some difference likely can be measured somehow but yeah ok they seem "neck and neck". there is some debate/ data over eg [citation counts](http://blog.geomblog.org/2007/07/stocfocssoda-cage-match-with-data.html)

Comment: @user6818 It will definitely be important enough for STOC/FOCS, as the method of interlacing polynomials has other uses as well. People are surely already working on it, for example Shayan Oveis Gharan.

Comment: @vzn They don't merge for two reasons. First, since they are organized by different organizations, it's bureaucratically very hard. Second, it will be very annoying to have only one important deadline per year. These problems are fixable in practice, and people are indeed thinking of merging at least the STOC/FOCS physical meeting to a "Theory Week".

Comment: In my last comment, I actually meant "in principle" rather than "in practice". We'll see about the practice.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus And has Shayan found an algorithm?

Comment: @user6818 Not that I know of.